# chain rule application to multivariate derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have a book with this in it:

[total derivative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKoFK.png)

But I don't understand where the single quote comes from.

If I look at this: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx

I would assume the total derivative to be:

[My take:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGbv0.png)

with dx/dt being x-dot and dt/dt reducing to 1.

But then I don't have a single quote, which indicates the partial of S with respect to x needs to differentiated with respect to time.

Could someone break down what i'm missing here?

Comment: What is $S$? what is $x$? Let's assume that $t$ is a real variable. I'm not sure what's implicit in this notation, can you provide us some more reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without the context (“I have a book” is useless information – tell us *which* book it is!), but my guess is that the prime means matrix transposition (like in Matlab, for instance), and that they view the gradient $\partial S/\partial \mathbf{x}$ as a column vector which must be turned into a row vector in order to be multiplied by the column vector $\dot{\mathbf{x}}$.

Comment: the book is 'optimal control systems' by desineni naidu

Comment: S is the terminal cost part of a functional, so the product should be a scalar. I think you are right, I was too hung up on ' being differentiation to consider the bold face of the x.